# How to read all records from Kafka (from start to beginning) and then stop the StreamingContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

How do I achieve the following using Spark Streaming for Java API?

1. Read all the messages from kafka log compacted topics ( i am using this to store all the user profile data ) Each message is profile data for a single user.
2. Once all the data has been consumed do not wait for next data to come in kafka pipeline and stop streaming context.

I am pretty new to spark streaming api and i dont know how to make spark streaming context stop waiting for more messages to come and progress ahead with whatever data it has.

Answer (score 0):

You should then use [KafkaUtils.createRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$) that:

> Create an RDD from Kafka using offset ranges for each topic and partition. This allows you specify the Kafka leader to connect to (to optimize fetching) and access the message as well as the metadata.

That will pull in all the records per `offsetRanges`.

Comment: Perfect. This is what i needed. I will try this.